# E212: Error Cannot open file for writing (VIM - .startup extension)

Tags: linux, vim, nano

I have look through various responses to similar questions but none of the solutions have helped me.

I am getting the error:

> "/pc1.startup" E212: Cannot open file for writing

I understand you cannot open a .startup file in notepad and edit it then save it as the .startup extension but I am struggling with finding a way to write the changes to my hard drive. Nano also gives me the same issue. If anyone knows any solutions that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that "various responses" have brought these up already, but for lack of detail I can only state the obvious:

Editors (mostly) don't care for file extensions, but the location matters a lot. As you're attempting to write to the *root directory* (`/`), you need to be root to be allowed to write there.

As I don't understand why a `*.startup` file needs to be there, it would be best to store it elsewhere. In Vim, you can do this via `:saveas ~/pc1.startup` (choosing your *home directory* instead). If it needs to be there, launch Vim as the root user with `sudo vim /pc1.startup` instead.

Comment: Thank you, my problem (being new to Linux) was that I was on /pc1 thinking I was adding to the directory I was CD'd into. I did not realise that put it onto root. It is working now, thanks :)